# Why request in View results in a tree listener shows "No data to display" in non-gui mode

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, jmeter, python-requests

Expected **Requests** and **Response** are showing after executing **jmeter script** in **GUI mode** but when the same is execcuted in **non-gui** mode, for few requests it shows **"No data to display"** and Response is empty.

This was encountered in jmeter v4. Can anybody help as in why such variance in requests when script is executed in non-gui mode?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY4fq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVKGe.png)

Comment: Can you show the corresponding  HTTP Request ?

Answer (score 0):

This is done intentionally, JMeter removes request and especially response data from sample results (mainly because it cannot be stored in CSV format) in order to reduce memory consumption and disk IO required to aggregate and store the data.

If you **really** need to see request and response data you can "tell" JMeter to store it by adding the next lines to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the properties up. Once done - re-run the test and make sure to use the different output .jtl file (or delete the existing one) - this time it will have much more results suitable for displaying in the View Results Tree listener

References:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)

Comment: Hey, it isnt working for me, I added above lines to user.properties file, changed outputl file name and restarted jmeter, now all the requests are showing NO DATA TO DISPLAY

Comment: I just configured again and see request and response but it doesnot show values that were passed. Shows NULL. Please check screenchot in question above.